# My SSIS Web Service Task is modifying XML result to omit a parent node, what gives?

Tags: xml, web-services, ssis

I am calling a web service using the SSIS 2012 Web Service task.  The XML that the HTTP call returns is much like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <GetFooResponse xmlns="http://acme1234">
         <GetFooResult>
            <Foo FOOTYPE_CODE="2" FOOTYPE="Premium" FOO_CODE="11" FOONAME="example" ACTIVE_INACTIVE="A"/>
            <Foo FOOTYPE_CODE="1" FOOTYPE="Standard" FOO_CODE="12" FOONAME="example2" ACTIVE_INACTIVE="A"/>
         </GetFooResult>
      </GetFooResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But when I debug in SSIS after storing the result XML in a variable or file on disk, I see the XML stored is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetFooResponse xmlns="http://acme1234">
    <Foo FOOTYPE_CODE="2" FOOTYPE="Premium" FOO_CODE="11" FOONAME="example" ACTIVE_INACTIVE="A"/>
    <Foo FOOTYPE_CODE="1" FOOTYPE="Standard" FOO_CODE="12" FOONAME="example2" ACTIVE_INACTIVE="A"/>
</GetFooResponse>
```

I am really at a loss to how this is possible--**how could SSIS be stripping out an intermediate node?** I am fine with it stripping the outer SOAP elements, but **where did GetFooResult go?** As a result, my XSD is no longer correct; I can't get a working SSIS package unless I fudge the XSD manually.

Any ideas how I can fix this so the SSIS Web Service Task results in the same XML that is retrieved from the web service task?

Comment: Is the `FOOTYPE_CODE` attribute value really changing, too? (The closer you can make this input and output to the real thing, the more likely you are to get a good answer. Having code "much like" the real code is likely to make people suspect that the problem is something that you haven't posted...)

Comment: I have only changed the names and values to protect proprietary information. I'll fix the inconsistency.

Comment: You say you're seeing this while debugging in SSIS. How are you doing that exactly? What's the result in the actual file, when outputting to a file?

Comment: Yes..by right-clicking the package in Visual Studio and choosing execute. When I output to a file as part of the task, I get the XML noted above, even though the XML returned over the wire had the GetFooResult element (verified with Fiddler).

Comment: Can you humour me for a moment, delete the XML file and re-run the package?

Comment: Sure...yep, same thing.  I edited to add the XML declaration for completeness.

Comment: So, is there just the Web Service task directly outputting to a disk file? (Perhaps I'm behind the times, only running SSIS 2008, but I'd have expected that to result in the XML result being encoded in a string in the file, not actually being the direct file contents.)

Comment: Yes, I can choose file or variable as the output.  The contents of either are the same.

Comment: (I have seen this before) Your first example is via a code interface like WCF so you are seeing some of the transport protocol stuff in there as well.   I see this with Async Silverlight calls for example.  The SSIS looks like REST like calls and gives back the actual result.   Interestingly you can control this via config in your web service, but it will break your app to make them the same.

Comment: Can you tell me more? I don't see how a web service change could cause the SSIS to splice out an internal XML node.